# Manage fragment life cycle with navigation drawer

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, navigation-drawer

I have an architectural issue in my application . I have used one activity with navigation drawer and several fragments .Now ,

Suppose I have two fragments A and B . navigation structure is somewhat:

A

```
   A1
   A2
```

B

```
   B1
   B2
```

where A1,A2 are of type A fragment and B1,B2 are of type B fragment. The only difference between same type of fragments eg. A1,A2 is of data .

**my first approach :**

whenever user click on A1,A2,B1,B2 . I just create a new instance of that type and replace the fragment.

```
  Fragment fragment =A.newInstance();

 private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(rlDrawer);
    }
```

**Note :** I do not want to add them to back stack.

Later on I realize this approach is inefficient as every time it will crate a new instance on that fragment even if they are of same type . As I said before the difference is only in data .So, I move to next approach

**Second Approach :**

Now my activity has Data member (references) of Fragment A and B . Now I will check if it is null only then create a new instance else just change the data :

```
   if (A == null) {
            a = A.newInstance();
        } else {
            ((A) a).changeData();
        }
        replaceFragment(a);
```

Problem with this approach is that when I switch from fragment A1 to B1 the A1 fragment get destroyed but its reference remain with activity . Now When i switch back from B1 to A1 it will not create a new instance as you can see in above code but at the same time onCreate() method gets called on Fragment A.

Should I remove the reference from activity as soon as onDestroy() is called on a Fragment ?

Does my second approach is correct ?

Is there any better approach for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would slightly modify your first approach.

Use string tags for your fragment.
When you are replacing a fragment use the `replace` method with three parameters, example:

```
  fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, TAG_A1).commit();
```

where `TAG_A1` is a unique String tag.

You can use the method [findFragmentByTag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag%28java.lang.String%29) from the [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) to check if the fragment was already created before you do a replace.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragmentA1 = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_A1);
if(fragment == null) {
    fragment = A.newInstance();
}
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, TAG_A1).commit();
```

Comment: I know that we can use findByTag() but I have heard that we should avoid this as it is a performance degrade as per romain guy talk at google I/O.

Comment: I haven't watched the talk, but I assume it's better than creating new fragments every time. Also you are not calling it very often.

Comment: Yes that is true that it is better then creating new fragment every time but as in my second approach I am not doing it. That is why I asked that is there any better approach as well to achieve it.